# How to prevent Kendo UI Pie Chart Tooltip from drawing outside parent Div?

Tags: css, telerik, tooltip, pie-chart, kendo-ui

I'm using Telerik's Kendo UI pie chart. I'm using the following configuration for the Tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    visible: true, 
    template: "${ category } - ${ value }%"
},
```

My category names are getting cut off because the Tooltip labels are too large. Is there a way to alter the location of where the Tooltip is displayed?

Comment: doee the tooltip : have an overlay property

Answer (score -1, accepted):

can you try playing around with the overlay or does the tooltip have an overlay property

```
overlay: {
   gradient: "none"
}
```

Comment: setting the gradient to "None" had no effect on the position of the tooltip. It simply disabled it.

Comment: are there other things in the overlay that you can play with.. this could be what is keeping you from positioning it properly.. that's why I put that out there.. sorry I did not make it clear the first time properties within the overlay. for example does it utilize a border: or anything like that.. I have the controls on my VMWare instance at hoome not here at work.. sorry.. otherwise I could try the same thing out for you

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure about moving the tooltip as you would have to do it for all of them and it might not look great. What about wrapping your text in the tooltip?  You can do that by specifying normal white-space in your template.  The parent of the tooltip template forces it into one line so you have to override that.

Checkout this fiddle here and see if this gets you closer to something that works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/burkeholland/JZrAt/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you don't want the word wrap suggested in Burke's answer

`.k-tooltip { width: auto }` worked for me.